# Adding Bootstrap and a logo png to Apostrophe CMS

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, apostrophe-cms

I am simply trying to add a `bootstrap.min.css` file with its corresponding `bootstrap.min.js` file to an Apostrophe CMS project. I have no idea how to simply add a static resource. I have the following in my app.js

```
'apostrophe-assets': {
    stylesheets: [
        {
            name: 'bootstrap.min',
            minify: false
        },
        {
            name: 'site'
        }
    ],
    scripts: [
        {
            name: 'bootstrap.min',
            minify: false
        }
    ]
}
```

but alas, it does nothing. I have removed the `.min` versions as well and tried those, still nothing.

On that note, I need to be able to link to a `.png` that will be used in my navbar, but I have no idea where to store any static resources for the website.

Is there a place I can just drop static files that I don't want pushed as `apostrophe-assets` so they are rendered and consumed properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

For this to work, Apostrophe needs the files to be located at:

`lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public/css/bootstrap.min.css`

And:

`lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Within *your project* (don't copy them into node_modules). You create your own `lib/modules/apostrophe-assets` folder within your own project, to parallel the one in the apostrophe npm module.

This is [as documented here in the tutorials on pushing assets](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/pushing-assets.html).

(If you have trouble pushing the CSS file, try renaming it with a `.less` extension and let me know you had to do that. It ought to be unnecessary though.)

Of course there is also nothing keeping you from overriding any of the blocks in `outerLayoutBase.html` in your own templates to insert script and link tags, but that shouldn't be necessary. If you follow the practice I'm recommending your files will minify with everything else in production.

Comment: I am going to try this. Quick note, there seems to be a typo in [this](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/pushing-assets.html) article. When it runs through adding scripts to the assets module it says it will look for `lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public/css/site.js` instead of `lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public/js/site.js` and the comments in that code snippet reference less and css.

Comment: I tried this with the basic `bootstrap.css` and I did have to name it to `bootstrap.less` for the bootstrap file to be included in my site. No matter what I did `bootstrap.min.css` or `bootstrap.min.less` could not be included. I got a parse error when I tried to use the min file.

Comment: Another question, can I include image files in the `apostrophe-assets` module?

Comment: Bootstrap uses Popper.js for there dropdowns or other components, I've added the popper.min.js and it doens't work. Bootstrap still doesn't recognize the popper.min.js file. Is there other way to use this with apostrophe?

Comment: Did you push that asset with apostrophe? What does that part of your configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `apostrophe-assets` module to push css and js files the same approach as provided by @boutell. For pushing `js` files it's ok, but for `css`  I've got a parse error related to bootstrap css. So it's because the apostrophe tries to compile it into css whereas it is already css.

To solve this problem I've override the `outerLayot.html` Nunjucks template. So basically in the file 
`node_modules/lib/modules/apostrohpe-templates/views/outerLayout.html`, we have:

```
{% extends "outerLayoutBase.html" %}
```

Which itself extends the `outerLayoutBase.html`

`node_modules/lib/modules/apostrohpe-templates/views/outerLayoutBase.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {{ apos.assets.stylesheets(data.when) }}
    {% block standardHead %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    {% endblock %}
    {% block extraHead %}
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body class="{% block bodyClass %}{% endblock %}">
    {% block apostropheMenu %}
      {{ apos.adminBar.output() }}
    {% endblock %}

    {% if data.user %}
    <div class="apos-ui">
      <div class="apos-context-menu-container">
        {{ apos.pages.publishMenu({ publishMenu: data.publishMenu, page: data.page, piece: data.piece, bottom: true }) }}
        {{ apos.pages.menu({ contextMenu: data.contextMenu, page: data.page, bottom: true })}}
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="apos-refreshable" data-apos-refreshable>
      {% block beforeMain %}{% endblock %}
      <a name="main"></a>
      {% block main %}{% endblock %}
      {% block afterMain %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    {{ apos.assets.templates(data.when) }}
    {{ apos.assets.scripts(data.when) }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
      {{ data.js.globalCalls }}
      {{ data.js.reqCalls }}
    </script>
    {% block extraBody %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I have used `{% block extraHead %}{% endblock %}` block and overrided it into a new file which is:
`/lib/modules/apostrohpe-templates/views/outerLayout.html`

```
{% extends "outerLayoutBase.html" %}

{% block extraHead %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
{% endblock %}
```

In the above file is included CDN of bootstrap css  and works as expected. **Note the path of this new file**. The `lib` folder is under the root folder not the `node_modules`.